# How to place individual articles into individual div's

Tags: templates, html, joomla, customization

I want to please know how to place individual 'articles' into individual CSS 'div's...??

Basically my design has my web page split into 4 different columns.. I want be able to place  individual articles in each one of those columns...

At the moment, Joomla will place each article directly under each other, for instance in the 'right' section of the template, without allowing me to insert any 'div's between the articles..

So maybe what I'm asking is how to add more sections to my template.. By sections i mean 
Eg. 'Banner' 'left' 'right' 'footer' 'disclaimer' etc... ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with modules as well.
Edit your template index.php file, and insert the divs where you want with the corresponding float:

```
<div id="left">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="" />
</div>

<div id="right">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="" />
</div>
```

Where the left,and the right ids are set in the template css file with the floats and etc.

Next is to include the positions into templateDetails.xml to the right place, like this:

```
<position>left</position>
<position>right</position>
```

Now you can create modules (Custom HTML modules) with the text/content, and position the created modules into the right or left position name.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer! When i place this code in it appears on every page... How can I get it to appear on select pages eg, only the 'Home' page...?

Comment: In the modules options there is a "Menu Assignment" section, there you choose "Select Menu Item(s) from the List", and you click on the HOME menu. If there is just the HOME menu is highlighted with blue, your module appears just in the Home screen !

Comment: ok, got it! But... the divs i place on the index file still stay on every page because it uses the same php file to make all the other pages, how do i stop that from happening...?

Comment: There are php file for every template layout, like the front page, and the category blog layout, and the catagory list and etc, try to find those, and insert the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla templates use CSS as a styling tool. 
In order to add new sections to your template you must change your Cascading Style Sheets (*.css files).

Splitting your main content into four sections requires a bit of CSS magic and you should read up on the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html), the [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) property and [this](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/) extensive tutorial.

One way of doing it using CSS is

[image: CSS four columns]

You can also do it with tables of course, just declare four columns.

Comment: I know how to use CSS pretty fluently !! I have already styled the page top to bottom... 

The problem is that in the index.php page, the PHP script displays the articles one after another with a single line of code..

I want it to be able to access the 'Atricles' individually so i can then assign them to unique DIV's, that may have different widths fonts etc...???

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, you might want to look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementByID)... you can access individual elements by ID with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple template override. Assuming that you are listing a blog style category, then make a copy of /public_html/components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php and put it in /templates/your template/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php. Edit that file to your liking then style accordingly. If you are not using blog category listing, just find the corresponding template file in the com_content views folder and use that.

Read this - http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Once you learn how overrides work it will change how you use Joomla.